# Habilitar um botão após colocar senha

Tags: c#

Preciso de um ajuda, mas não sei como posso fazer este código.

Tenho um form e nesse form tenho um  botão que faz exclusão em uma tabela do SQL, quero fazer com que o botão fique desabilitado e para habilitá-lo quero fazer com que o usuário digite uma senha.

Segue o código do botão que chama a formulário pra digitar a senha.

```
private void btnExcluir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frmExclusao excluir = new frmExclusao(txtID.Text);
    excluir.Show();
}
```

segue o código do formulário de senha.

```
private void btn_Ok_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("Confirma a exclusão do cadastro", "Atenção", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM tbl_amostra WHERE ID = '" + txtID.Text + "'";
        cmd.Connection = conex;

        conex.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conex.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Poderia nos dar mais detalhes? Seu projeto é web? Se sim, está usando alguma biblioteca JavaScript tipo jQuery, Angular...? Edite sua pergunta com maiores detalhes, assim é mais fácil te ajudar.

Comment: Bom dia. Não e web e um executável em c#, preciso fazer o seguinte quando abrir o form o botão ficar desabilitado, quando eu clicar com o mouse em cima do botão desabilitado ele abrir um novo form, digitar uma senha e dar ok e ai sim, habilita o botão para fazer a exclusão do dado.

Comment: O que conseguiu ate o momento?

Comment: Seu projeto é Win Forms, WPF...? Quanto mais detalhes puder fornecer, mais fácil podemos responder à pergunta. Se possível coloque um print screen na pergunta para termos uma ideia melhor do que deseja fazer.

Comment: Você quer clicar num botão desabilitado? ._.

Comment: Isso mesmo clicar em um botão desabilitado ele chamar um outro formulário, solicitando uma senha para habilitar o botão

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entendendo que seu projeto é `winform` quando você fala em "Tenho um Form", utilize o evento TextChanged do TextBox:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ButtonDelete.Enable = (textBox1.Text == "1234");
}
```

Comment: Rovann mas nesse caso o botão vai estar em outro formulário, porque o campo com o textbox para digitar a senha não e o mesmo formulário que esta o botão, o seu código acima vai funcionar?

Comment: mostre o código onde você chama o segundo form, pelo primeiro, e o código do form que digita a senha, que então adéquo o código a sua situação.

Comment: Deu certinho aqui com a opção que vc deu acima, ajustei o form e deu certo.